# Spread the discount evenly

Tags: sql

We have a table of purchases with the following columns: positionName nvarchar(150), positionCost numeric(10,2).

We are given a discount @discount int = 100. We need to distribute it evenly among all items. For example:
Item 1 / 200 / 50
Item 2 / 20 / 50
The cost of the second item is lower than the discount itself
I made the following query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, @discount / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchases) AS sk
    FROM purchases
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN sk > positioncost THEN positioncost
            ELSE sk
       END AS discount
FROM cte;
```

Result:

Item 1, price: 200, discount: 50

Item 2, price: 20, discount: 20

Question: How to add the remaining discount (30 $) from the second item to the first item?

Comment: Can you give your actual input and expected output ? Cursors can be a solution.

Comment: Also you are tagging mysql and t-sql ? these are 2 different RDBMS.

Comment: Removed conflicting tags.

Comment: How are you determining the order in which you are applying discounts to rows?

Comment: Post a few more examples of the spread. What if the total cost is less than the discount for example?

Comment: @NickW summary of discounts must be extended by the number of lines

Comment: @shawnt00 I figured out this problem. example of my question. if the cost of the product is 70, then the discount is calculated to be 100 for each product, then in this discount there will be 70, but the situation is 30, you need to spread it over other products.

Comment: I’m not sure you answered my question. If you have three costs of 70, 40, 30 and a discount of 70 then what are the rules to say whether you use all the discount for the 70 or use it for the 30/40 and none for the 70 - or some other distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by 'evenly'; would you be happy to distribute proportinately?  ie Item1 gets 100/220*200, and Item2 gets 100/220*20

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the first item, adding the unused portion is a simple calculation that can be done with a `sum()`. This could result in a negative cost for that item though also.

```
with dataX as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (order by positioncost desc) as rn,
        -- should this be a fraction?
        -- should the total be exactly equal to the @discount?
        -- presumably you want to round down so that the total can't exceed @discount
        @discount / count(*) over () as sk
    from purchases
), dataY as (
    select *,
        case when sk > positioncost then position else sk end as discount
    from dataX
)
select *,
    case when be rn = 1 then
        positioncost - discount - 
          -- unapplied discount
          (@discount - sum(discount) over ())
        else positioncost - discount end as finalcost  
from dataY;
```